# Python bar_chart_race error - 'Exception: You do not have ffmpeg installed on your machine.'

Tags: python, pandas, video, ffmpeg

What I've done:

- pip install ffmpeg-python in command prompt
- download ffmpeg from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ (ffmpeg-git-full.7z)
- extract .7z into new folder in C: called ffmpeg
- edit the user environment variables and add C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-2022-03-21-git-505a7d39cd-full_build\bin to path [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Obr9.png)
- check ffmpeg is installed with ffmpeg -version in command prompt, (ffmpeg is installed)
- try to run a python script using bar_chart_race in pycharm, receive error message below

```
Exception: You do not have ffmpeg installed on your machine. Download
                            ffmpeg from here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html.
                            
                            Matplotlib's original error message below:

                            boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2
```

python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import bar_chart_race as bcr

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

points = df[['date', 'var1', 'var2']]
points.set_index('date')

bcr.bar_chart_race(df=points[:10], filename='video.mp4')
```

I've followed these steps from various youtube videos and posts, and I'm completely lost.

I've also tried to run the same script in a jupyter notebook, same result.
Tried a different path for the project, same result.
Tried on a different device, same result.
Tried moving the ffmpeg.exe to the same path as my python script (read on a related post), same result.

Forgot to add: I have tried using ffmpeg in krita (an animation software), and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for reading, any help you could offer would be welcome.

Comment: What happens if you do `os.system('ffmpeg')`? Also, you need to reopen terminal/ide after you set your env path for the change to take effect.

Comment: @kesh yeah sorry should have said, I've reopened both and restarted the computer a few times, <os.system('ffmpeg')> returns the same thing as ffmpeg -version in the command prompt: <ffmpeg version 2022-03-21-git-505a7d39cd-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma>... (too long to post enitrely)

Comment: @kesh sorry for the poor formatting of the reply, this is the first time I've used stackoverflow, and thanks for your reply

Comment: No worries (but do remember that you cannot format comments as much going forward). So, it is visible from Python. Weird. The python package sounds interesting, so let me take a peak at the source code to see if I can discover something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is not FFmpeg, and `bar_chart_race` is displaying an incorrect exception message. The one from `matplotlib` is the actual error:

```
indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2
```

This error does not imply anything about FFmpeg. I suspect the issue is that your pandas dataframe is not compatible with `bar_chart_race`. I'm guess this because you have 2 columns in `df`.

I suggest trying to call their example code to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so stupid not having tried a different dataframe.

The problem was that I didn't have inplace=True when setting the index!!

Comment: Oh I should've caught that as I was OJTing `pandas` just today. Glad you figured it out.